# wordpress function to validate cart

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to ask for your assistance with the following:
I have different kinds of subscriptions on my site. One "basic" subscription (it's variable subscription with ID 286)  and multiple "add-on" subscriptions (simple subs).
Every subscriber has to be subscribed to the "basic" subscription - it's ok.

My problem is that I need to prevent subscribers who do not have an active (wc-active) subscription to the "basic" subscription to check out with any "add-on" subscription without the basic subscription in the cart as well.

I can check if the user has active subscription with this code:

```
wcs_user_has_subscription( $user_id, $productId, 'active' );
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure the other function to use. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation* hook